# Apply near clip to CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

How to apply near clip to CALayer. Sublayers with z value greater than 0 are not hiding.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you can't do this. Core Animation layers are not true 3D. I don't think there is a clipping volume in CA like there is in OpenGL.

If you need this level of sophistication, you need to write your animation in OpenGL.